# TimeZone Codes in DateTime Formatter

Tags: c#, .net

I have DateTime string in following format:

> 3/15/24 4:25:51.000 PM EST

And I need to parse it. I was able to work out template as below:

> M/d/yy h:mm:ss.fff tt K

And it's almost OK, but iit doesn't recognize "EST" code and it shows TimeZone as below:

> 3/15/24 4:25:51.000 PM -05.00

How could I cope with this? How can I provide format for TimeZone codes?

Comment: Those aren't timezone names or codes, they're [ambiguous abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). A single abbreviation may be used for multiple timezones, eg IST is used for Irish, Israel and India Standard Time. There are 3 CSTs, 2 GSTs, 3 BSTs etc

Comment: If you parse the string into a DateTimeOffset (at least I assume that you do so), there is only the offset information (UTC-05) left, the string "EST" is gone. You may be able to reconstruct it from the list given by @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @KlausGütter EST may be unique but a lot of other abbreviations aren't. As the Jodrell's answer in the duplicate explains, there's no way to unambiguously map abbreviations. The application will have to make assumptions and accept the risk. Someone in Ireland will map IST to Irish time, someone in India to India time.